# Is there a remaining duration of the profile data in the IGO_Profile?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contact-deletion, sfmc-einstein

do someone know if there is a remaining duration of the profile data in the IGO_Profile. Will the data be deleted after a certain period of time? Unfortunately, I haven't found anything.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The IGO/PI data extensions have no default retention settings applied. And then there is no systematic process outside a [GDPR delete request](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/pb-create-batch.htm) that will remove records from these DE. So once data is placed in these DE it will remain.